# Load same component with different data by pushing a button

Tags: javascript, view, routes, react-native

I got my React Native app with some different views.

What I want to achieve is to "go" or to "load" the same component but passing different data.

I'm using [React Native Simple router](https://github.com/react-native-simple-router-community/react-native-simple-router) to change between views.

I gonna try to explain it with an example.

I got **viewA.js**:

```
...

var viewB = require('./viewB');

...

goToViewB: function(id){
    this.props.toRoute({
      name: "View B",
      component: viewB,
      passProps: { id: id },
    });
  },

...

<TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.goToViewB.bind(this, 10) } underlayColor="transparent">
    <Text>Go to View B</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

...
```

And this on **viewB.js**

```
...

var viewB = require('./viewB');

...

goToViewB: function(id){
    this.props.toRoute({
      name: "View B",
      component: viewB,
      passProps: { id: id },
    });
  },

...

<TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.goToViewB.bind(this, 20) } underlayColor="transparent">
    <Text>Go to View B with different data</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

...
```

I hope this example explain it better.

I go **viewA** -> **viewB** -> **viewB** (loading different data) -> **viewB** (loading different data)....

I'm pretty new with React Native, so if you guys suggest another approach would be ok too.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reload the data in View b without reloading the route, you could do it in this way:

**viewB.js**

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        data: ''
    }
},

componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({
    data: this.props.id
  })
},

changeData(data) {
  this.setState({
     data: data
  })
},

<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.changeData('70') } underlayColor="transparent">
    <Text>{ this.state.data }</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

As you can see, when the component mounts, it sets the props data in the state. That way, when you need to change the data, you call **this.setState()** to reset the data.

Comment: Thank you man!

I think I'm ok with your solution, but, just to know, do you think there is any way to achieve what I said? To go to the same component but passing different data.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you mean go to the same component? Do you want to reload the component? If so, are you wanting it to flicker, or what effect do you want to show the component is reloaded?

Comment: For example, as I said, I'm using React Native Simple router to navigate between components in my app.

When I load a different component, a "swipe" effect appears. I'd like something like this. That is because I wanted to "load" the same component but with different data, to get this effects.

Thanks.